# cron job, birthday check, and sending email (just making sure)

Tags: php, email, date, cron

I have created send_bday_email.php which send birthday email 2 weeks prior to customer's birthday.

```
<?php

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$todayMD = date('m-d');

include_once "../../mysqli_connect.php";
$sql= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM Customer_Info");
$mail_body = '';

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $email = $row["email"]; 

    $birthday = $row['birthday'];

    $bday = new DateTime($birthday);

    $bday->sub(new DateInterval('P14D'));

    $twoWeekbday = $bday->format('m-d');

    if ($todayMD==$twoWeekbday) {
        if(empty($row["firstName"])){

            $name = 'Customer';

        } else {
            $name = $row["firstName"];
        }

        $mail_body = file_get_contents('../forms/bday_email_form.html');
    }
}
```

This is my part of code which has two weeks prior and if customer's two week prior is equal to today send birthday email.

If I run this code daily using cron job, will it send emails perfectly?

I wanted to make sure before I actually test it out with my customer.

Comment: i used todayMD so that year does not interrupt my ($todayMD==$twoWeekbday) code.

Comment: you can test it on your test server....

Comment: dont delete (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540534/cron-job-on-two-week-prior-to-databases-birthday) and re-ask, its really insulting

Comment: um I delete my post because the question was very broad. I asked this question after making php file just to make sure with you guys. If it was insulting. sorry about that. Pretty new to community and php